# Optimize scraping through list of urls and write to csv

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, beautifulsoup, numpy-ndarray

With a csv of 20k+ urls I want to scrape and find the html element "super-attribute-select". If found, write the url to column A, along with the product number(sku) to column B. If not found, write url to column C and sku to column D. Finally, save the dataframe to a csv file.

If i run the following code it works, but my program runs out of memory. It liked to find a way to optimize this. Now ~1500 urls take 5 hrs to process. While the entire csv is 20k.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series


urlList = pd.read_csv(r"url.csv")
urlList = urlList.url.tolist()
notfound = []
found = []
skulist =[]
skumissinglist =[]


# Function scrape, pass url, open with soup, and find class
def scrape(url):
    tag ='select'
    classused = "super-attribute-select"
    d = dict(A=np.array(found), B=np.array(skulist), C=np.array(notfound), D=np.array(skumissinglist))

    try:
        content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
        sku= soup.find("div", {"itemprop": "sku"}).string
        result = soup.find(tag, class_=classused)
        #soup returns None if can't find anything
        if result == None:
            notfound.append(url)
            skumissinglist.append(sku)
        else:
            found.append(url)
            skulist.append(sku)

    except:
        result = print("Some extraction went wrong")

    df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, Series(v)) for k, v in d.items()]))
    df = df.to_csv('Test.csv')

for i in urlList:
    scrape(i)
```

Comment: For memoty optimization do : each time you scrape a row dump it into the csv using 'with .... open', for time optimization use multithreading instead of the sequential loop process

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I would try a few things:

(1) Update a dictionary instead of appending to a list.  I think dictionaries are faster and more memory-efficient than lists.

(2) Rather than export each URL result as a CSV with the same name, either (a) preferred: wait until you are done to export all results as a single CSV, or (b) worse: maybe export them to different filenames by using f-strings instead of overwriting 'Test.csv' every time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pool either with gevent or the built in one from urllib3 (or requests).  Then you could do 10, or 100 a time depending on poolsize, and use an async queue to get remaining ones as the pools get exhausted.

```
from gevent import monkey, spawn, joinall
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pool import Pool as GeventPool
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlList = pd.read_csv(r"url.csv")
urlList = urlList.url.tolist()
pool = GeventPool(10)
notfound = []
found = []
skulist =[]
skumissinglist =[]
count = len(urllist)

# Function scrape, pass url, open with soup, and find class
def scrape(url):
    tag ='select'
    classused = "super-attribute-select"
    d = dict(A=np.array(found), B=np.array(skulist), C=np.array(notfound), D=np.array(skumissinglist))

    try:
        content = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
        sku= soup.find("div", {"itemprop": "sku"}).string
        result = soup.find(tag, class_=classused)
        #soup returns None if can't find anything
        if result == None:
            notfound.append(url)
            skumissinglist.append(sku)
        else:
            found.append(url)
            skulist.append(sku)

    except:
        print("Some extraction went wrong")

    df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k, Series(v)) for k, v in d.items()]))
    return df.to_csv('Test.csv')

pool.map(scrape, urllist)
```